# Remove values from specific columns with a condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to remove values in the value1, value2, value3 and value4 columns if the 'on status' column contains the string 'new'

Data

```
id  date        location    on status   value1  value2  value3  value 4
CC  1/1/2022    ny          new         12      1       0       1
CC  4/1/2022    ny          new         1       1       8       9
CC  7/1/2022    ny          new         1       1       1       0
CC  10/1/2022   ny          new         1       2       2       1
CC  1/1/2023    ny          ok          1       2       2       1
```

Desired

```
id  date        location    on status   value1  value2  value3  value4
CC  1/1/2022    ny          new         
CC  4/1/2022    ny          new         
CC  7/1/2022    ny          new         
CC  10/1/2022   ny          new         
CC  1/1/2023    ny          ok          1       2      2         1
```

This only works on the first 2 columns, but it actually adds two additional columns (value3 and value4 and deletes the data from all rows not just the conditional 'new'
Any suggestion is appreciated

Doing

```
df.loc[(df['on status'] == 'new'),  ['value1', 'value2','value3', 'value4']]= ''
```

Comment: @added a solution, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
df.loc[(df['on status'] == 'new'), ['value1', 'value2','value3', 'value4']] = ''
```

OR

```
df.loc[(df['on status'].str.strip() == 'new'), ['value1', 'value2','value3', 'value4']] = ''

df
```

```
    id  date    location    on status   value1  value2  value3  value4
0   CC  1/1/2022    ny      new                 
1   CC  4/1/2022    ny      new                 
2   CC  7/1/2022    ny      new                 
3   CC  10/1/2022   ny      new                 
4   CC  1/1/2023    ny       ok             1      2       2       1
```

Comment: Hi Naveed thanks this is exactly what I have in my post and this does not work

Comment: i just noticed it :(   why it works for me? can you post your result? I wonder if the value 'new' has some whitespaces around it

Comment: try to strip the "on status" before comparing

Comment: right I see the issue now, the column names had spaces thanks

Answer (score 1):

sample input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    
    "on_status" : ["new", "new", "new", "new", "ok"],
    "value1" : [x for x in range(5)],
    "value2" : [x for x in range(5)],
    "value3" : [x for x in range(5)],
    "value4" : [x for x in range(5)],
})
```

it does work for me using loc

```
df.loc[(df.on_status == "new"), ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]] = ''
```

sample output

```
on_status   value1  value2  value3  value4
0   new             
1   new             
2   new             
3   new             
4   ok  4   4   4   4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(df['status'].str.strip() == 'new'),  ['value1', 'value2','value3', 'value4']]= ''
```

try this as mentioned Naveed, if there are whitespaces around then it will check by stripping white spaces.

Comment: thanks! i added that as alternate solution

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.loc[i,'on status'] == 'new':
        df.loc[i,'value1': 'value 4'] = ' '
df
```